# Front end login form not working on live site

Tags: front-end

I am using the front end form submission. It works on localhost perfectly, but it's not working when my site is live. It shows the "success message", but originally it's not logged in. This is my code:

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'log-in' ) :    
    global $error;
    $login = wp_login( $_POST['user-name'], $_POST['password'] );
    $login = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $_POST['user-name'], 'user_password' => $_POST['password'], 'remember' => $_POST['remember-me'] ), false );

    if (!$error) {
        save_message( 'success', __( 'You have successfully Login.', 'frontendprofile' ) );
        unset($_POST);
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( 4 ) );  
    }
    // wp_redirect( home_url() );
endif;
```

So what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use wp_login function it is deprecated , instead use [wp_signon](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon).
wp_signon function returns WP_Error on failure so use it to evaluate condition as following.

```
<?php
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == 'log-in' ) :

$login = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $_POST['user-name'], 'user_password' => $_POST['password'], 'remember' => $_POST['remember-me'] ), false );

if ( !is_wp_error($login) ){ 
save_message( 'success', __( 'You have successfully Login.', 'frontendprofile' ) );
unset($_POST);
wp_redirect( get_permalink( 4 ) );
}

endif;
?>
```

Comment: Your code is still not working having same problem.

Comment: Is it displaying success message?

Comment: Yes it displaying success message but not logged in

Comment: Can you just show me your whole code of registration model including from where you are passing user-name, password etc.

Comment: Sory for the late reply. Yes i can email you the file with all code. just provide me you email i will email you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set cookie, I modified your code as below:

***Updated***

```
<?php
function parse_user($info = null, $return = 'object') {
    if ( is_null( $info ) ) {
        global $current_user;
        if ( empty( $current_user->ID ) ) return null;
        $info = get_userdata( $current_user->ID );
    }
    elseif ( empty( $info ) ) {
        return null;
    }
    if( $return == 'ID' ) {
        if ( is_object( $info ) ) return $info->ID;
        if ( is_numeric( $info ) ) return $info;
    }
    elseif( $return == 'object' ) {
        if ( is_object( $info ) && $info->ID) return $info;
        if ( is_object( $info )) return get_userdata( $info->ID );
        if ( is_numeric( $info ) ) return get_userdata( $info );
        if ( is_string( $info ) ) return get_userdatabylogin( $info );
    }   
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

function wp_login_user_po9856($username, $password, $remember) {
    // Get the user based on the username from the POST
    $user = parse_user($username);

    // Remove html tags from the variables
    $username = strip_tags($username);
    $password = strip_tags($password);

    // Validate the Form Data
    if(!wp_check_password( $password_stripped, $user->user_pass ) ) return new WP_Error('incorrect_password', "Wrong Password!");

    // User login
    $login = wp_signon(array('user_login' => $username, 'user_password' => $password, 'remember' => (bool)$remember));
    if (is_wp_error($login))
        return $login;

    // Unset
    unset($_POST);

    // Custom Message
    save_message( 'success', __( 'You have successfully Login.', 'frontendprofile' ) );

    // Redirection
    wp_redirect(get_permalink( 4 ));
}
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && @$_POST['action'] == 'log-in')
{
    wp_login_user_po9856($_POST['user-name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['remember-me']);
}
```

?>

Comment: It is not mandatory to set cookie, the registration can work without setting secure_cookie parameter for the wp_signon function.

Comment: Your code stuck the page it display nothing. Not working properly.

Comment: @VinodDalvi it's not registration, it's about login, however WP DOC stated `This function sets an authentication cookie. Users will not be logged in if it is not sent`, using that function also makes sense.

Comment: @Adi are u sure u removed your code completely and then paste mine ?

Comment: @rev yes i completely remove my code and paste your code.

Comment: The tow function you write `parse_user();` or `isEmptyString();` is not working. These function are not for php.

Comment: @rev WP DOC stated wp_signon function sets an authentication cookie. Users will not be logged in if it is not sent. yes it is true and the wp_signon function sends the cookie but you are confusing it with wp_signon function second parameter and this parameter is about Whether to use secure cookie and not normal cookie. I have tested it and the function wp_signon is working without using secure cookie.

Comment: @Adi, yes you were right about `parse_user()` i thought that i included it! but about `isEmptyString()` it's supported. I updated my code.

Comment: @VinodDalvi Compromise! Edited.

Comment: @rev it still not working it just refresh the page. This is the link of my site check it if you want [http://demo.webdezyner.com/tripgoggle/login-user/] and `username/password` is `trip`.

Comment: @Adi your input fields are not wrapped with `form` tag. your form tag started and ended consecutively without anything between: `<form id="loginForm" action="http://demo.webdezyner.com/tripgoggle/login-user/" method="post"></form>`

Comment: @rev i fix it. But not working still.